# Attribute is not declared for element

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation

Im doing the xsd document for a XML and i have declared the attribute for my element but it doesn´t seem to work, thanks in advance

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<clase xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xs:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="2.xsd">

  <asignatura id="1">

  <nombre cuatrimestre="2">Lenguaje de Marcas</nombre>

  </asignatura>

</clase>
```

XSD

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="clase">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="asignatura">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              
              
              <xs:element name="nombre">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:simpleContent>
                  <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                    <xs:attribute name="cuatrimestre" type="int"></xs:attribute>
                  </xs:extension>
                  </xs:simpleContent>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>


            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:string"></xs:attribute>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    </xs:schema>
```

I have tried to switch the mixed attribute for the ComplexType element but still don´t work

Comment: What is the error you're getting? You need to say more than just "it doesn´t seem to work"

Answer (score 0):

The error lies at this line:

```
<xs:attribute name="cuatrimestre" type="int"></xs:attribute>
```

You need to change the 'int' to 'xs:int':

```
<xs:attribute name="cuatrimestre" type="xs:int"></xs:attribute>
```